# How to select and recognise "patterns" with Notepad++?

Tags: sql, regex, notepad++

I've been working on a SQL server database, and had to make the "insert data" script again.

For this, I picked the whole "create" one and ditched out the parts that were not about data.

Now, I need to remove the id parts of the query, I managed pretty easily to remove the sart of it but I struggle with the end.

Basically, I need to turn

`INSERT [dbo].[sometable] ( [table_id], [table_field], [table_field2]) VALUES (id, 'some stuff', 'some stuff')`

Into

`INSERT [dbo].[sometable] ([table_field], [table_field2]) VALUES ('some stuff', 'some stuff')`

Someone knows how to do that?

ok, maybe i'm not clear enough, but for instance, i have this :

```
INSERT [dbo].[motclef] ( [id_motclef], [motclef], [motclef_trash], [createur], [ipcreateur], [datecreation]) VALUES (100, 'ftp', 0, 'xxxxxxxxx', '110.20.65.128', NULL)
```

and i want to have this :

```
INSERT [dbo].[motclef] (  [motclef], [motclef_trash], [createur], [ipcreateur], [datecreation]) VALUES ( 'ftp', 0, 'xxxxxxxxx', '110.20.65.128', NULL)
```

Comment: i think i need something like "if they're ints, delete caracters between a ( and a , and then delete the , as well"

Comment: Parsing something like the SQL (or any other language) isn't a task for regex (too complicated, too many traps). You should use a dedicated parser for SQL language (modules/libraries are available in many programming languages).

Comment: Have done that 1000's of times. Usually you can do someting like string replace `] ( [table_id],` with `] (`, and replace `VALUES (id,` with `VALUES (`. (I.e simple replace, not regexp-replace.)

Comment: *if they're ints*: How is the regex supposed to know if they're *ints* or not? It can't analyze your table to see what the column type is, and there's no use of *int* in your sample INSERT statement. Is the column you want to remove always named `[table_id]`? (I doubt it.) How would the regex be able to identify which one  to remove and which ones stay? Your question is unclear in that regard, and if you can't explain it to us you can't write a regex to do it; you need to be able to clearly define what should match **and** what should **not** in order to do this with a regex.

Comment: @jarlh, that's so simple i didn't thought of it :o but how can you you select id since it's a number ? you know, doing something like 'VALUES ( + next caracters until blank space'

Comment: @Orsu, yes, something like that, replace `VALUES ( some integer ,` with `VALUES (`, using regexp. (I use to do it in emacs...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to match:

```
\([^,]+,
```

And replace with the following:

```
(
```

Explanation:

- `\(` : match opening bracket
- `[^,]+` : match everything other than `,` (comma)
- `,` : match comma

**PS:** Assuming you only have insert scripts in the file

Comment: notepad++ says that "([^,]+," is an invalid regular expression, am i missing something ? ps : could you please also explain me what does that regexp means exactly ? it seems like black magic to me

Comment: Thank you so much, i add to alter the regex a little : "\([0-9999]{1,5}," and now it works :D